# R: Editing a column so it can be merged

Tags: r, string, merge

I have 2 data sets I need to merge with a common column using R, but they need to be changed to show the same format but cant find how to.
One column looks like this

```
BT0-3
BT0-4
BT0-5
```

While the other looks like this:

```
BT0_3.5
BTO_4.5
BT0_5.5
```

I just need to make them match so I can merge them (The numerical values are labels so the extra 0.5 is just recorded differently)

Answer (score 2):

If your question is how to replace '-' to '_', then it would be:
var = sub(pattern = '-', replacement = '_', x = var)

If you would like to drop '.5', then:
var = sub(pattern = '.5', replacement = '', x = var)
would simply do the job.

The difference between function 'sub' and 'gsub' is 'gsub' replace everything met the pattern while 'sub' only replace the first match on the left. I would recommend to use sub if you don't know your data well, and try 'grep' to find improvement after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Do all of the values in both columns begin with `BT0`? In the second column, one of the values is typed as `BTO`. Is that a typo? Assuming both columns' values begin with `BT0`, make sure both columns are of character (rather than factor) mode, then:

```
df$var = gsub("_([0-9])\\..$", "-\\1", df$var)
```

where `df$var` is the data frame and column you want to change. This will replace the underscore before a digit with a hyphen and remove a period followed by any character at the end of the string.